# How to use the diff function of R on a column of a dataframe conditional on having a particular value in a different column

Tags: r, dataframe, diff

The dataset I am working with has average riderships of different kinds of public transportation and in different years. I am interested in creating a new column showing the increase of the average ridership from the year before for each type of public transportation. 
The code I tried to use is the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(public_trans$type_of_public_transport)) {
  if (public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i] == public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i+1]) {
    ridership_diff[i] <- ifelse(public_trans$average_ridership == 0, 0, public_trans$average_ridership[i+1] - public_trans$average_ridership[i])
    next}}
```

The output I get running the code is this:
"Error in if (public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i] == public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i +  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

By changing the start of the loop from "1:length(public_trans$type_of_public_transport))" to "0:length(public_trans$type_of_public_transport))", the output error becomes:
"Error in if (public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i] == public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i +  : 
  argument is of length zero"

Also, even if my code worked, I'm pretty sure that there is an easier and more direct way to obtain the result I want.

Comment: `i + 1` becomes an issue at the last row. You may have `for (i in 1:(length(public_trans$type_of_public_transport) - 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens when the loop reaches the last row and `i + 1` doesn't have an entry. The OP also mentioned about starting the index from 0, but `R` index starts from 1.  An option is to loop until the last row

```
for (i in 1:(length(public_trans$type_of_public_transport) - 1)) {
    if (public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i] == 
         public_trans$type_of_public_transport[i+1]) {
 ridership_diff[i] <- ifelse(public_trans$average_ridership[i] == 0, 0, 
      public_trans$average_ridership[i+1] - public_trans$average_ridership[i])
}}
```

---

`ifelse` is vectorized, so we don't need a loop here

```
ridership_diff <- with(public_trans,  ifelse(type_of_public_transport[-1] == type_of_public_transport[-nrow(public_trans)] & average_ridership[-nrow(publlic_trans)] == 0,
        0, average_ridership[-1] -average_ridership[-nrow(public_trans)]))
```